# Cannot add property innerHTML, object is not extensible when trying to add html to a ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What am I doing wrong here? I am using React.CreateRef(); to first create my reference then I assign the reference to my div with the id 'arrows'. I then call this reference in my placeInDiv function. In this function when I try to do this.arrowRef.innerHTML = b . I get the following error.

> Cannot add property innerHTML, object is not extensible

Im not sure how to add html into a div with react.

```
placeInDiv = (arr) => {

    const b = (
        <div className={`${this.sliderData.length === 5 ? 'd-xl-none' : ''} arrow-container`}>
          {arr[0] == true &&
          <img onClick={() => this.setDirection("previous")} className="arrow-left" src={ArrowRight} /> }
          {arr[1] == true &&
          <img onClick={() => this.setDirection("next")} src={ArrowRight} /> }
        </div>
    );


    //add html b to arrowRef
   console.log( this.arrowRef.innerHTML)

  }

  render() {  
    return (
      <div className="content-slider-wrapper">
        <div className="content-slider-title">
          <span>PRODUCTS OF THE WEEK</span>
        </div>
        <div className={`${this.sliderData.length === 5 ? 'mt-xl-5' : ''} content-slider-container`}> 
          <div className="test-right" id="slider-move">
            <Carousel 
                ref={ref => (this.carousel = ref)}
                breakPoints={this.breakPoints} 
                disableArrowsOnEnd={true}
                renderPagination={({ pages, activePage, onClick }) => {
                  let arr;
                  arr = this.getAmountOfPages(pages, activePage);

                  this.placeInDiv(arr);
                  return (
                    <>
                      <div className={`${this.sliderData.length === 5 ? 'd-xl-none' : ''} black-slider-container`}>
                        {pages.map(page => {
                          const isActivePage = activePage === page
                          return (
                            <div className={isActivePage ? 'black-slider' : 'blank-slider'}
                              key={page}
                              onClick={() => onClick(page)}
                              active={isActivePage}
                            />
                          )
                        })}
                      </div>
                    </>
                  )
                }}
                >
                {this.sliderData.map((item, index) => (
                  <div key={index} className="carousel-item-container">
                    <div className="carousel-image-container">
                      <img src={top} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="carousel-text-container">
                      <ul>
                        <li className="carousel-text-container-title">{item.title}</li>
                        <li className="carousel-text-container-text">{item.typeOfProduct}</li>
                        <li className="carousel-text-container-text line-through">RRP {item.rrp}</li>
                        <li className="carousel-text-container-text line-through">Our Price: {item.ourPrice}</li>
                        <li className="carousel-text-container-text">Sale Price: {item.salePrice}</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </Carousel>
          </div>
        </div>   
        <div className="ggg" id="arrows" ref={r=>this.arrowRef=r}>
<p>dasda</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you are trying to use a ref here.  You could just show the code or not based on a condition you set, such as local state.

Comment: I think I understand what your saying but could you provide an example

Comment: Use `<div className="ggg" id="arrows">{this.state.b}</div>`. For this to work you'll have to introduce `b` as a state eg. `this.state = { b: <p>dasda</p> }` in the constructor. Then use use `this.setState({ b: ... })` instead of `const b = ...` in `placeInDiv`.